# Optimize all MySQL tables using MyISAM

Tags: mysql, myisam

i found great article here http://www.empulsegroup.com/?p=342

But when i try:

```
root@vps:~# for i in `mysql -e 'select concat(table_schema,".",table_name) from information_schema.tables where engine="MyISAM"'`; do mysql -e "optimize table $i"; done
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected
```

1. can you give me some example to use it?
2. how to optimize --all-databases?

many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the statement in that article, you probably don't need to run optimize table very often. It really won't make queries run much faster.

But let's talk about the error you got and how to fix it.

The first line out output of your query is not a table name, it's the column heading, which in this case is the expression you used.

```
for i in `mysql -e 'select concat(table_schema,".",table_name) from information_schema.tables where engine="MyISAM"'`; 
do
  echo "$i";
done
```

Output:

```
concat(table_schema,".",table_name)
test.m
```

(I had to create a table `m` that was MyISAM, because I don't use MyISAM normally, and I recommend that [you should not use MyISAM either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb/17706717#17706717).)

If you want to skip the column heading, use the `-N` or `--skip-column-names` option.

```
for i in `mysql -N -e 'select concat(table_schema,".",table_name) from information_schema.tables where engine="MyISAM"'`; 
do
  echo "$i";
done
```

Output:

```
test.m
```

You may also want to delimit the schema and table name, because either name might be a reserved word.

```
for i in `mysql -N -e 'select concat("\`",table_schema,"\`.\`",table_name,"\`") from information_schema.tables where engine="MyISAM"'`; 
do
  echo "$i";
done
```

Output:

```
`test`.`m`
```

Answer (score 1):

You specify the database to use for the `mysql` command by using the [`-D` or `--database=...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_database) argument.